# Updating Table View After Publish

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, updating

This is not an error question, but a general coding and xcode question. I am making a stock app and I need to have a updating tableview for me to write my OWN articles onto that tableview. Is there a way to connect the table view to a document or something after the publish so I can keep putting articles on the page.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a database.**

Access the data from your app by using URLSessions(thats something in swift/objective c).  Call GET method urls to run a php script that accesses the database with your articles via mysql commands. Then echo the returned articles in a json_encoded string in your php script. Then in your URLSession, parse the json and update your table view.

Your question was really general so here's a general answer to get you started.